# This version of CLI is only compatible with Angular versions ^15.0.0, but Angular version 14.2.12 was found instead

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli, typescript-typings, angular-upgrade

I am upgrading my application from angular 13 to 14.
For angular 13 everything was working fine but after doing the angular 14 updates I am facing this error and am unable to understand where I am making the mistake.
Node: 14.21.1
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6nGj.png)

I tried to changing "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^13.3.10" but no luck

Comment: Please confirm the node version.

Comment: Node version - Node: 14.21.1

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to:
https://github.com/manfredsteyer/ngx-build-plus/issues/361

Your issue seems similar to this one and the resolution would be the same mostly but in case you want to get it fixed by the `TPL` author

You will have to figure out which TPL is causing the issue run

```
yarn list @angular-devkit/build-angular
```

This would tell you which `TPL` requires the 15 version of angular in your project.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: for npm use ```npm ls @angular-devkit/build-angular```